# What are the access rules of "Standard access rights" and "Object-specific access rights" in Access Mask

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, acl

I used [NtObjectManager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NtObjectManager/1.1.33) to get permissions of the named pipe `\\.\pipe\InitShutdown`:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $a = Get-NtFile("\Device\NamedPipe\InitShutdown")
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $a.SecurityDescriptor.Dacl

Type    User                         Flags Mask
----    ----                         ----- ----
Allowed Everyone                     None  0012019B
Allowed NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON None  0012019B
Allowed BUILTIN\Administrators       None  001F01FF

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $a.SecurityDescriptor.Dacl[0].Mask | fl


IsEmpty           : False
HasAccess         : True
HasGenericAccess  : False
HasSpecificAccess : True
Access            : 1180059
```

The named pipe has access mask `1180059` to everyone.
Here is the [MSDN Access Mask Format guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-mask-format?redirectedfrom=MSDN):
[image]

Converting `1180059` to binary:

```
00000000 00010010 00000001 10011011
```

Bits 0,1,3,4,7,8,17,20 are enabled but there is no description what is exactly the permissions for "Standard access rights" nor "Object-specific access rights".
With ProcessHacker we can see the exact permissions:
[image]

Is there documentation for the meaning of "Standard access rights" and "Object-specific access rights" ?

I tried to search for answers in ["AccessControlListAcl"](https://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/accesscontrollistacl2_1.html) and ["Permissions Not Included In .NET"](https://blog.cjwdev.co.uk/2011/06/28/permissions-not-included-in-net-accessrule-filesystemrights-enum/)

I found [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/standard-access-rights) about "Standard access rights" but it only shows five rules while the pictures shows it has 8 bit flags:

```
DELETE
READ_CONTROL
SYNCHRONIZE
WRITE_DAC
WRITE_OWNER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
[Access mask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-mask-format?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
format is:

| Bits | Rights |
| --- | --- |
| bits 0 - 15 [16 bits]: | object-specific rights |
| bits 16 - 23 [ 8 bits]: | [standard access rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/standard-access-rights?redirectedfrom=MSDN) |
| bit 24: [ 1 bit]: | right to access SACL (ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY) |
| bits 25 - 27 [ 3 bits]: | reserved |
| bits 28 - 31 [ 4 bits]: | [generic access rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/generic-access-rights?redirectedfrom=MSDN) |

The **generic access rights** in the four high-order bits specify each
a set of standard and object-specific access rights.
They can be called "macros", where
each bit is mapped to a set of standard and object specific rights,
as depending on the object type.

For example, for files and folders, the
[mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-security-and-access-rights) is :

| Access right | Description |
| --- | --- |
| FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE | FILE_EXECUTE, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE, SYNCHRONIZE |
| FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_READ_DATA, FILE_READ_EA, STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ, SYNCHRONIZE |
| FILE_GENERIC_WRITE | FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_WRITE_DATA, FILE_WRITE_EA, STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE, SYNCHRONIZE |

But the mapping would be different for
[Process Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

The
[**Standard Access Rights**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/standard-access-rights)
are called standard because they are common to almost all object types.
These are (as you found) :
DELETE, READ_CONTROL, SYNCHRONIZE, WRITE_DAC, WRITE_OWNER.

The **object-specific rights** are, as the name says, specific and
understood only in the context of their object type.

If we look at the object-type of process, we have
[Process Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
with unique rights for processes, for example PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME.

To get a list of the rights for all the object types in Windows
would be a colossal task, and I'm not sure that the documentation by
Microsoft is detailed enough for it.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the permissions of a simple file I created and each time add\remove an advanced permission, then I run the following commands from [NtObjetManager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NtObjectManager/1.1.33):

```
PS C:\tmp\permissions> $a.Dispose()
PS C:\tmp\permissions> $a = get-ntfile("a.txt")
PS C:\tmp\permissions> $a.SecurityDescriptor.Dacl

Type    User                             Flags     Mask
----    ----                             -----     ----
Allowed Everyone                         None      00140000
```

In this way I was able to map the mask for each individual permissions, this is probably won't show exactly what is each bit but can give a good understanding:

```
Read:                          00000000 00010010 00000000 10001001 : 00120089
Read & Execute:                00000000 00010010 00000000 10101001 : 001200A9                          
Write:                         00000000 00010000 00000001 00010110 : 00100116                          
Read & Write                   00000000 00010010 00000001 10011111 : 0012019F                          
Read & Write & Execute         00000000 00010010 00000001 10111111 : 001201BF                          
Modify                         00000000 00010011 00000001 10111111 : 001301BF
Full                           00000000 00011111 00000001 11111111 : 001F01FF
  
All advanced permissions separated: 
List folder / Read data        00000000 00010000 00000000 00000001 : 00100001
Read Attribute                 00000000 00010000 00000000 10000000 : 00100080
Read Extended Attributes       00000000 00010000 00000000 00001000 : 00100008
Read permissions               00000000 00010010 00000000 00000000 : 00120000
Traverse folder / execute      00000000 00010000 00000000 00100000 : 00100020
Create files / write data      00000000 00010000 00000000 00000010 : 00100002
Create folders / append data   00000000 00010000 00000000 00000100 : 00100004
Write attributes               00000000 00010000 00000001 00000000 : 00100100
Write Extended attributes      00000000 00010000 00000000 00010000 : 00100010
Delete                         00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000 : 00110000
Change permissions             00000000 00010100 00000000 00000000 : 00140000
Change ownership               00000000 00011000 00000000 00000000 : 00180000
```